# CSS files in Laravel 5.1 not accessible, not found

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, laravel-5.1

I am trying to include a css file to my page. I have done this in my blade template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/frontend.css')}}">
```

I then my css file in `{laravel_root}/public/css/frontend.css`

The resulting page outputs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://hbnw.app/css/frontend.css">
```

But using chrome's development tools I see that upon request the server returns a 200 OK response but the file is empty.

I am running in a homestead environment. Do I need to do something with Laravel 5's routes or is there a completely different workflow for css? Could I just change the htaccess to return the files for all requests starting with /css and /js?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the file empty or can not be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel doesn't process files in the public folder. The `.htaccess` that comes with Laravel only sends requests through the Laravel routes (index.php) when they don't match an existing file or folder in the public directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was wrong but it's working now. My apologies.